# Angular 4 ng build base-href duplicate subdirectory

Tags: angular, web-deployment

I'm deploying builds of my angular app to an s3 bucket with different subdirectories based on the branch name. The urls look like:

```
pr.example.com/add-cool-spinner
pr.example.com/increase-awesomeness
```

If I deploy using `--base-href /add-cool-spinner` it properly updates the base tag: `<base href="add-cool-spinner">`. However when redirecting or generating links the subdirectory doubles, so link tags generated from the router look like:

```
pr.example.com/add-cool-spinner/add-cool-spinner/page
```

I've tried changing only `--deploy-url` instead, but then it doesn't update the base href tag, and references root url (`pr.example.com/page`).

Have any hints for not doubling up the base url directory? Is this a bug or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 23):

Turns out that this isn't super well documented, but angular is expecting a proceeding and trailing slash. So deploy with:

```
ng build --base-href /add-cool-spinner/
```

It still isn't referencing images correctly that are in image tags, and that might be because of known bugs in the builder.

Comment: Indeed, we changed from `--base-href en` or `--base-href en/` to `/en/` and it started working. Thank you! I just wonder why does it happen like that in `ng build`. Eg. why they don't auto-correct it or report as error/warning. Any idea?

Comment: This is still required with Angular 8.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Adding a trailing slash makes Angular look for static files in a local path, e.g. `C:/Documents/styles.scss`

Comment: This is still required with Angular 11 too.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out adding prepending with a  slash solves the problem
how ever for most terminals it will just point to your local bash root
to solve this just build with trailing slash

```
 ng build --base-href "apppath/"
```

and update the index.html with a slash at the beginning

```
<base href="/apppath/">
```

I am not sure how we can automate the build process with this workaround

Update

```
ng build --base-href "."
```

this seems to work in my case

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem and in the `index.html` I put  `<base href="/">`
and then I build with `ng build --base-href="/mypath/"`